# Sharing Android NDK Lib

Tags: android

The Native Code of the Android application is going alone with application as lib file in the APK file. Suppose if I want to share a native code between two different applications, Is there any trick avail apart from the below:

1. Adding the lib with every application
2. Copy the lib in to system/lib folder and dynamically link it with application. (If we build just only the applications then we cannot use this).

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy anything onto /system unless you are root, so I'd suggest you just include your native library in every application that needs it.

Comment: But you can copy to your application data directory, maybe you can load the library with an absolute path? Don't know much about how you can do that with JNI. Or maybe have a small native lib in every app that loads your big library manually (dlopen, dlsym...).

Answer (score 0):

You must create library project ant than create your activity and lib.so file. You may be added all project this library.(Such as vitamio)